# pyautogui taking full screen when region is designated

Tags: python, screenshot, pyautogui

I have a script written in Python3.5 with the module pyautogui to take note of an area on the screen and then break it up into four quadrants. I am doing this to speed up searching while subsequent scripts run. To test if I am getting quadrants I have a call to the screenshot command in the function getQuad1. When it runs it gets the entire screen, not just the quadrant that I have designated.

I am not sure if I fouled up my algebra or if it is the module that is acting up.

```
import pyautogui

def areaSetup(dimTop, dimBot):
    workSpace = getWorkSpace(dimTop , dimBot)
    W, H, Hh, Wh = getWaHWorkSpace(workSpace)
    quad1 = getQuad1(workSpace,W, H, Hh, Wh)
    quad2 = getQuad2(workSpace,W, H, Hh, Wh)
    quad3 = getQuad3(workSpace,W, H, Hh, Wh)
    quad4 = getQuad4(workSpace,W, H, Hh, Wh)
    return workSpace, quad1, quad2, quad3, quad4

def getWorkSpace(browTopLeft, browBotRight):# gets the full area of workspace
    top = pyautogui.locateOnScreen( browTopLeft , grayscale=True)
    while top is None:
        top = pyautogui.locateOnScreen( browTopLeft , grayscale=True)
    print (top)
    bottom = pyautogui.locateOnScreen( browBotRight , grayscale=True)
    while bottom is None:
        bottom = pyautogui.locateOnScreen( browBotRight , grayscale=True)
    print (bottom)
    x1, y1, h1, w1 = top
    x2, y2, h2, w2 = bottom
    #x2 = x2+w2
    #y2 = y2+h2
    print ("initial print" , x1, y1, x2, y2)
    workSpace = x1, y1, x2, y2
    print ("Workspace" , workSpace)
    return workSpace

def getWaHWorkSpace(workSpace):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = workSpace #break it into four parts again
    W = int(x2 - x1) #get the height
    H = int(y2 - y1) #get the width
    Hh = int(0.5 * H) #get mid point of height
    Wh = int(0.5 * W) #get mid point of width
    print ("W and H" , W, H, Hh, Wh)
    return W, H, Hh, Wh

def getQuad1(workSpace,W, H, Hh, Wh): #North West Quad
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = workSpace #break it into four parts again
    q1x1 = int(x1)
    q1y1 = int(y1)
    q1y2 = int(y1+Hh)
    q1x2 = int(x1+Wh)
    quad1 = q1x1, q1y1, Wh, Hh 
    print("quad1", quad1)
    pyautogui.screenshot('quad1.png' , region=quad1)#SCREENSHOT TEST
    return quad1
```

Generally areaSetup is run with the top left corner of the browser window and the bottom right corner of the same window ( this is designed to fiddle with browser forms ). getWorkSpace runs and gets the full workSpace area , essentially the dimensions of the browser window. Then there is a script called getWaHWorkSpace which then calculates out the Width, height, and halves of each for subsequent use.

I then have a function called getQuad1 which does the math needed to designate the top left quadrant of the screen. There are three more functions that get the other quadrants , they're identical to the getQuad1 function save for the variables used.

Any advice or thoughts regarding this would be thoroughly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some running around I found that this works in Windows but not in Linux ( Ubuntu 16.04 at least ). I kept the code the same and it works as expected in Windows.